# From where can I get the debug symbols for System.Web.Mvc.dll?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, reference-source

The Visual Studio debugger reports that the Microsoft Symbols Server does not have symbols for `System.Web.Mvc.dll`.

Where may I find them if I don't want to compile the source myself?

Comment: [Using Symbols and Source Server for Official Releases](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debug%20Official%20Symbols%20and%20Source)